# Ebay API with description

Tags: ebay-api

How do I get the Ebay API to return a description?

I have some code that makes an API call as follows:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?
callname=findItemsAdvanced&
responseencoding=XML&
appid=appid&
siteid=0&
version=525&
QueryKeywords=keywords;
```

It returns items, but it's missing the full description text. I'm not seeing the next step to ask for the detailed descriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use Shopping API, for instance: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#sampledescriptionitemspecifics

Comment: What's the difference between the Shopping API and the Finding API?

Comment: The finding API is a lite-weight API designed to allow your application to provide a quick list of items (aka no details).

Comment: Can someone help me find the ShippingProfileID, ReturnProfileID and the PaymantProfilID ? –

Answer (score 1):

I use following (very simple function to get Item detail from ebay):

```
function eBayGetSingle($ItemID){
   $URL = 'http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping';

   //change these two lines
   $compatabilityLevel = 967; 
   $appID = 'YOUR_APP_ID_HERE';

   //you can also play with these selectors
   $includeSelector = "Details,Description,TextDescription,ShippingCosts,ItemSpecifics,Variations,Compatibility";


   // Construct the GetSingleItem REST call         
   $apicall = "$URL?callname=GetSingleItem&version=$compatabilityLevel"
            . "&appid=$appID&ItemID=$ItemID"
            . "&responseencoding=XML"
            . "&IncludeSelector=$includeSelector"; 
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

   if ($xml) {
     $json = json_encode($xml);
     $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
     return $array;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: This approach now requires an oauth token