# Ebay Api description field not returning a value

Tags: python, ebay-api

My eBay `item.get()` request does not retrieve anything for the seller description and goes straight to my error message displayed when not found `.all` other parts do return a value - I want the seller description to be shown under item name.

I tried changing the description to `Item.Description` , `textdescription` - nothing works - also tried `.get('value')` at the end of it.

```
import pandas as pd
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as Finding
from ebaysdk.exception import ConnectionError
from IPython.display import display, HTML

APPLICATION_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

def get_user_input():
    # Get user input for the search keyword
    search_keyword = input("Enter the item you want to search for: ")
    return search_keyword

def get_category_id(api, search_keyword):
    try:
        # Use findItemsByKeywords to get category information
        response = api.execute('findItemsByKeywords', {'keywords': search_keyword})
        items = response.dict().get('searchResult', {}).get('item', [])

        # Choose the first item's category as an example; you may want to implement logic to handle multiple items
        return items[0].get('primaryCategory', {}).get('categoryId')
    except ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)
        print(e.response.dict())

def get_results(api, payload):
    try:
        response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', payload)
        return response.dict()
    except ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)
        print(e.response.dict())

def search_ebay(api, search_keyword, category_id):
    payload = {
        'keywords': search_keyword,
        'categoryId': [category_id],
        'itemFilter': [
            {'name': 'LocatedIn', 'value': 'GB'},
        ],
        'sortOrder': 'StartTimeNewest',
    }

    results = get_results(api, payload)

    if results is not None:
        total_pages = get_total_pages(results)
        items_list = results['searchResult']['item']

        i = 2
        while i <= total_pages:
            payload['paginationInput'] = {'entriesPerPage': 100, 'pageNumber': i}
            results = get_results(api, payload)
            items_list.extend(results['searchResult']['item'])
            i += 1

        df_items = pd.DataFrame(columns=['currentPrice', 'viewItemURL', 'primaryCategory', 'galleryURL', 'title', 'description'])

        for item in items_list[:3]:  # Display only the first 3 items
            row = {
                'currentPrice': item.get('sellingStatus').get('currentPrice').get('value'),
                'viewItemURL': item.get('viewItemURL'),
                'primaryCategory': item.get('primaryCategory', {}).get('categoryName'),
                'galleryURL': item.get('galleryURL'),
                'title': item.get('title', 'N/A'),  # Get the title or use 'N/A' if not available
                'description': item.get('TextDescription', 'No description available'),  # Get the description or use a default if not available
            }

            df_items = pd.concat([df_items, pd.DataFrame([row], columns=df_items.columns)], ignore_index=True)

        return df_items
    else:
        print("No results found.")
        return pd.DataFrame()  # Return an empty DataFrame if no results

def get_total_pages(results):
    if results and 'paginationOutput' in results and 'totalPages' in results['paginationOutput']:
        return int(results['paginationOutput']['totalPages'])
    else:
        return 0

# Initialize the API connection
api = Finding(siteid='EBAY-GB', appid=APPLICATION_ID, config_file=None)

# Get user input for the search keyword
search_keyword = get_user_input()

# Get category ID dynamically based on the user's search term
category_id = get_category_id(api, search_keyword)

if category_id is not None:
    # Search eBay based on user input
    df_items = search_ebay(api, search_keyword, category_id)

    # Sort the DataFrame before selecting the first three items
    df_items_sorted = df_items.sort_values(by='currentPrice')

    # Display the HTML content with clickable links and images for the first three items
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)  # Show full content of columns, like URLs
    display(HTML(f"<h2>Top 3 Results for '{search_keyword}'</h2>"))
    display(HTML(df_items_sorted.head(3).to_html(escape=False)))

    # Display the cheapest item with all details in a formatted box
    cheapest_item = df_items_sorted.iloc[0]
    


    display(HTML(f"""
    <h2>Cheapest Item</h2>
    <div style="border: 2px solid #4CAF50; padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px; max-width: 400px; border-radius: 10px;">
        <img src="{cheapest_item['galleryURL']}" alt="Cheapest Item" style="max-width: 100%; border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 8px;">
        <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;">Price: £{cheapest_item['currentPrice']}</p>
        <p style="font-size: 14px;">Product: {cheapest_item['title']}</p>
        <p style="font-size: 12px;">Description: {cheapest_item['description']}</p>
        <p style="font-size: 14px;"><a href="{cheapest_item['viewItemURL']}" target="_blank">View Item</a></p>
    </div>
    """))
else:
    print("Unable to determine category ID.")
```

My error is here - at least I think so:

> 'description': item.get('TextDescription', 'No description available'),  # Get the description or use a default if not available

Comment: ask eBay if they send this information. Maybe you have to pay for it.

Comment: maybe first use `print(item))` or `print( item.keys() )` or `print( dir(item) )` to check what you have in variable

Comment: I wonder - `sellingStatus`, `viewItemURL`, `primaryCategory`,etc all are with lower first char - so maybe you should also have lower `t` in `textDescription`

Comment: in question [Ebay API with description - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002582/ebay-api-with-description) I see they use `includeSelector = "Details,Description,TextDescription,..."` in `request` - so maybe you have also use this in request.